# bundle.js not found (404) when I host an app on Flask

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack

I'm trying to run my react-based web-app on a simple Flask server that I set up. I using webpack to bundle all my front-end packages. However, I've found that when I run the server, the javascript file created (bundle.js) is not found.

My webpack configuration (webpack.config.js) is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
  entry: [
    './index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
```

Where bundle.js is outputted to the /www/ directory.

Also in the /www/ directory is my index.html file:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>HERE</p>
        <div id = "image-upload"></div>
        <div id = "sudoku_game"></div>
        <script src="/bundle.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally. The Flask server that I wrote is very simple:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../www", 
            template_folder = "../www")

@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

As you can see, bundle.js and index.html are in the same directory on the same level.

When I run the server (using python server.py). localhost:5000 displays "HERE" but then throws:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/bundle.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Interestingly, when I run the same app on an Express js server, there is no problem as bundle.js is found. The reason why I want to switch to Flask is that I have python scripts that I want to run on the server side.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? I suspected that for some reason bundle.js was never compiling, however the server doesn't find bundle.js even when I save it to the disk.

For reference, my directory structure is:

```
-sud(parent)  
-----node_modules  
-----server  
---------server.py  
-----src (has all my react code)  
-----www  
---------static (has css file)  
---------index.html  
-----package.json  
-----webpack.config.js
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/645, this article will give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

The file wasn't being found by your python Flask server because in this example `bundle.js` needs explicit generation by running webpack & it appears that you simply hadn't run the command to generate it yet.

Before your Flask server is able to serve your `bundle.js`, `bundle.js` has to first be built and compiled by running Webpack via a command like the one you posted in the answer.

Looking at your directory, I also don't see the `index.js` that matches what you're referencing in your webpack config yet, so it's not clear to me that you needed to be running webpack to generate a `bundle.js` at this stage.

Re your other point, I'm guessing that when you ran the Express server, you were using a start script which ran a webpack build in the process and so that's why a  `bundle.js` found by your Express server. The answer to that would likely be in the scripts section of your `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

So I did some more reading, and I found an answer that works, but I don't quite understand why it was necessary. Once I typed this line into the console:

```
webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js
```

everything worked as it should have.

Comment: This is simply to create the bundle.js file.